# Как сделать input ссылкой?

Tags: html

Или как сделать, чтобы `<input type='checkbox' name='pages' value='%s'><b>%s</b><input class='butto' type='submit' value='Выбрать элемент'>` без чекбокса при нажатии был выбран, а чекбокс я удалю. Делаю вывод всех страниц в админке, и нужно, чтобы после названия каждой страницы была кнопка или значек редактировать и удалить.

**обновление**

Делаю вывод всех страниц в админке, и нужно, чтобы после названия каждой страницы была кнопка или значек редактировать и удалить.
Например:

id 1) title [edit] [delete]

Надо, чтобы при нажатии edit по гет-параметру переходило на страницу edit.php с выбранным айди. В данном коде это работает, если поставили голочку чекбокса, а мне надо, чтобы было без него, так как я хочу убрать чекбокс.

Comment: Сломал мозг, извините, очень хотел помочь.

Comment: Я почти понял 2-е предложение, но не понял 1-го. Постарайтесь более внятно объяснить, что вы хотите, это повысит шансы получить ответ.

Comment: Формируйте такие ссылки:

    <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">edit</a>

где $id - id записи из БД.

Comment: Ну спасибо, это я и сам знаю.

Comment: Так в чем тогда проблема?

Comment: Всегда было интересно, почему в вопросах по html и js стоят теги php? Что это? Непонимание, где заканчивается php и начинается html?

По теме. Опишите поведение, какое хотите получить.